# How to create a PowerShell alias for [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode()?

Tags: powershell

I already figured out how to use UrlDecode in PowerShell:

```
PS Z:\> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
PS Z:\> [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line ")
```

I also figured out that I can load System.Web by adding corresponding command to `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1"` so I don't have to do this manually each time I open PowerShell.

However, I still have to type `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode` each time which is a hassle even when using tab to auto-complete.

Is there a way to create an alias so that instead of

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line")
```

I can just type

```
urdc("First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line")
```

or better yet

```
urdc "First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can create a simple wrapper function using automatic variables [`$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input) and [`$args`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#args):

```
function urdc {
    if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
        return $input.ForEach({
            [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($_)
        })
    }
    $args.ForEach({
        [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($_)
    })
}
```

Now you could use it like:

```
urdc "First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line" "First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line"
```

Or from pipeline:

```
"First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line", "First+Line%0D%0ASecond+Line" | urdc
```